# Selenium Web Scraping lenght of a movie

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to get the lenght of a movie using webscraping but it doesn't work.

I have the following code:

`lenght = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(2)").text`

but the result is not as expected. I get 12 and not 2h 56min and I don't understand why because I'm using the correct cssselector

movie url  = https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877830/?ref_=watch_fanfav_tt_i_1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there. it should have been `.sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(3)`

```
lenght = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(3)").text
```